# AndroidLint default rules location

Tags: android, lint, android-lint

I'm trying to learn more about android lints. So I want to see already implemented rules. I searched a lot but I couldn't find the location of these files.
Can someone give me the location or link to access these files?

Answer (score 0):

You can display them by launching this command:

```
$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools/bin/lint --show
```

For example in Mac default installation location:

```
/Users/tooflex/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/lint --show
```

Comment: thanks but this just shows their name, category, description etc. I want to read their code and how they are implemented.